# Perform unix operations after connecting to remote host using ssh

Tags: python, paramiko

Using paramiko to connect to remote host. How do i move across directories and perform unix operations? Sample code below

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('remote ip', username='username', password='password')
ftp = ssh.open_sftp()
ssh.exec_command('cd /folder1/folder2')
```

How do i perform operations like listing files in a directory, checking current working directory and perform other unix commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way (example on `ls` command):

```
import paramiko
import sys

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('x.x.x.x', port=22, username='user', password='pass')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')

# Wait for the command to terminate
while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
    # Only print data if there is data to read in the channel
    if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
        rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
        if len(rl) > 0:
            # Print data from stdout
            print stdout.channel.recv(1024),



ssh.close()
```

Comment: I tried this, but it does not list all files in the directory when i print stdout. I get an output like this <paramiko.ChannelFile from <paramiko.Channel 15 (closed) -> <paramiko.Transport at 0x9866f28 (cipher aes128-ctr, 128 bits) (active; 3 open channel(s))>>>

Comment: Don't know. Here it works. Have a look at the Paramiko docs for this (command SSHClient): http://docs.paramiko.org/en/2.2/api/client.html

Comment: I have edited my code, adding a waiting loop for stdout to terminate before printing.

Comment: if you fixed, do you mind checking the green arrow close to the answer? If not, pls post output error.